# Legacy Objective C : Potential Leak of the Object?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

**Hi, Appreciate the help.**

When i analyse the code through Xcode i am getting potential leak of the object obj. I am using legacy code with 32-bit environment. ARC is not supported. How can i manage the memory leak if it is called by other class.

```
 @implementation CfgCard

+       create
{
CfgCard *obj     = [ self new ];
obj->cardtype = HDW_CARD_NONE;

return( obj );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only methods that start with `new` or `init` are expected to return objects with +1 retain count. The easiest way to fix your code is to return `[obj autorelease]`. Note that you'll probably need to modify code that invokes this method to make sure you're not overreleasing returned object.

Alternatively, you can mark your `create` method as `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`.